# Do recent DC films share a continuity?

Tags: dc, continuity

I've not kept up with the recent DC films, Batman, Green Lantern, Superman etc.

Do these all share a continuity or are linked some how, in the same way that the Marvel films were linked and then led up to joint film?

Comment: Straight answer - No. Only `Green lantern` is planned to be a first installment for continuity of `Justice league` film and may be upcoming `Man of steel` is a part of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, they're not in a shared universe.

Batman is explicitly in its own universe.  The Nolans have [pretty thoroughly](http://io9.com/5555743/nolan-will-not-bring-back-the-joker-for-batman-3) stated that their films are not connected to any larger DC universe.

I recall reading rumors that *Green Lantern* included hooks for them to start building a shared film continuity, but given the poor performance of that film at the box office, it seems plans for follow up films were scrapped.  Having watched the film, having Amanda Waller in it in that role seems a bit *odd*, and I suspect she's the hook for that theoretical shared continuity.  In addition, there are many rumors that Ryan Reynolds is contracted to play Green Lantern in a future *Justice League* film.

There are also rumors that *Man of Steel* will include some hints as to a shared universe.  Since the movie's not released, and they haven't officially stated anything, this is unconfirmed.

I [dug up a rumor](http://movies.cosmicbooknews.com/content/exclusive-news-justice-league-movie) from last year that touches on this stuff:

> However, Henry Cavill and Ryan Reynolds could appear as their respective characters, Superman and Green Lantern -- but it is too early to tell.
>
> There is a strong indication that the Justice League movie will be part of a shared universe.
>
> WB wants another Superman movie released before Justice League; however, don't expect that story to be compromised for Justice League, as the next Superman film will still be treated as a stand alone film.
>
> Another Green Lantern film before Justice League is also a possibility. It's being said the Green Lantern sequel will definitely be better than the first as Sinestro will be the villain, and also that the sequel will act as the first step towards a joint universe in which hints towards other heroes can be integrated more easily (than lets say a Superman sequel).

So maybe in a few years, once they've made *Justice League*, there will be a DC Cinematic Universe.  But not now.

Answer (score 4):

They are talking about a Justice League film<sup>[1](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/L3VITIKUZ293/news/?a=67057)</sup>. The *new* Superman movie and (rumored) the Ryan Reynolds Green Lantern film would be in that canon. However, the Christian Bale Batman movies would *not* be.

Comment: They've been talking about making a *Justice League* movie for *years* at this point, call me skeptical.